# summation of product

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out the sum of the product of different combination of the numbers between 1 and 5

the sum should be

sum $= (5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1)+(5\times 4 \times 3 \times 2)+(5\times4\times3)+(5\times 4)+(5)$

I guessed the notation will look like this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^5  \prod_{i}^5 i $$

where i is 1 for the summation notation

if this is correct can some one help me with the formula

Comment: yes your right  .....

Comment: $5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1+5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2+5\cdot 4\cdot 3+5\cdot 4+5=5(4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1+4\cdot 3\cdot 2+4\cdot 3+4+1)=5(4(3\cdot2\cdot1+3\cdot2+3+1)+1)=\dots$  After all is simplified, you will have $5(4(3(2(1+1)+1)+1)+1)$.  Similarly if you have twenty terms it will be $20(19(18(\dots(2(1+1)+1)+1)+1)\dots +1)$.  This runs in $O(n)$ time instead of $O(n^2)$ time.

Comment: I don't see it simplifying further nicely, but perhaps [OEIS can help with that](http://oeis.org/A007526).

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there is a closed formula for this sum of products. JMoravitz's comment is probably the best option for a quick algorithm. It is also the approach used to evaluate polynomials quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to show the range of value for a sum and a product. The sum in your case is $1$ to $5$. It is also important not to repeat the variable used in another sum or product. We shall use $i$ for the summation variable and $j$ for the product variable. Giving

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^5 \prod_{j=i}^5 j 
\end{eqnarray*}

This can be rewritten as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^5 \prod_{j=i}^5 j =5(1+4(1+3(1+2(1+1)))) 
\end{eqnarray*}
Which is a continued product and can coded $O(n)$.

Comment: correct this is what i figured out, now what is the formula for this notation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the equation for this

Comment: Your formula gives $5\times 5!=600$ not $325$

Comment: @Raffaele No it doesn't - it starts the product at $j=i$. So when $i=1$, the product is $5!$, then when $i=2$, the product is $2\times3\times4\times5$, and so on.

Comment: @JohnDoe I swear I read both index $i=j= 1$. I am sorry...

Comment: @Raffaele That's OK ... don't worry about it ... but please put $j$ in for the product variable in your first equation.

Answer (score 3):

No. With that notation you get

$$\sum _{j=1}^5 \prod _{i=1}^5 i=5\times 5!=600$$

You want 
$$\sum _{i=1}^5 \prod _{j=0}^{i-1} (5-j)=325$$

Comment: is there is an equation for this???

Comment: Your first formula uses the variable $i$ twice. It is important to point out that this must not be done ... indeed another variable must be used.

Comment: i got this thanks, i need to simplify this as i'm writing a code for it, and i don't like the fact that this runs in O(n^2) "quadratic" which is not acceptable as n gets very large